# Scaling option similar as linux pdfnup scaling

Tags: python

I'm totally new to programming and I need to convert an `.sh` file to a `.py` file.

In this line:

```
pdfnup --nup 1x2 --no-landscape --scale 0.95 --suffix 'D' Lecture_0-D.pdf
```

How can we provide scaling in python pdfnup?

Comment: You might want to checkout [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself, but from the [pdfnup examples](https://pypi.org/project/pdfnup/#examples):

> You can use *pdfnup* as a Python module e.g. like in the following interactive Python session:
>
> ```
> >>> from pdfnup import generateNup
> >>>
> >>> generateNup("file.pdf", 8, verbose=True)
> written: file-8up.pdf
> ```

So presumably you could do this:

```
generateNup('Lecture_0-D.pdf', nup='1x2', no_landscape=True, scale=0.95, suffix='D')
```

But check `generateNup`'s documentation about parameters to be sure.

Comment: look at the generateNup function please........def generateNup(inPathOrFile, n, outPathPatternOrFile=None, dirs="RD",
        verbose=False):

Comment: There is no arg. like nup , no_landscape , scale , suffix